# Примеры проектов, содержащих механизм обработки исключений

Tags: c++, исключения

Приведите, пожалуйста, ссылки на проекты или фрагменты исходного кода, в котором интенсивно используется механизм обработки исключений.

Интересует именно код, в котором имеется своя иерархия классов исключений (возможно, наследуемая от `std::exception`), а также использование обработчиков `catch`.

Вопрос возник с связи с тем, что в текущем проекте я использую механизм исключений, выглядит он примерно так: у класса есть свой тип исключений, функция-метод генерирует исключение, ловит его обработчиком, в котором есть записывание в лог и генерация повторного исключения для вызывающей функции (это для каскадного определения ошибки). Еще в обработчиках иногда встречается код отката, но очень редко, поскольку ошибки проекта обычно не могут быть решены «на месте». Занимает это примерно 40% всего кода. В связи с чем я и хочу посмотреть, как реализуются обработчики в коммерческих проектах и как там строится иерархия классов исключений.

Я смотрел некоторые open-source проекты, но в основном натыкался на библиотеки, в которых функции объявлены либо как `noexcept`, либо как генерирующие некоторое исключение и т.о. передающие проблему вызывающему пользовательскому коду.

Comment: Дамаю найти нормальные проекты с интенсивными обработками исключений будет сложно, т.к. это не очень хорошее решение. Такое засилие "пустых" обработчиков очень сильно замусоревает код. Можно логировать момент бросания исключения через макрос. А catch писать только в том месте, где мы можем реально что-то сделать с данным типом исключения и обычно там ловят по базовому классу std::exception& и только в очень редких случаях по реальному типу исключения. В описание std::exception.what() можно записать достаточно информации чтоб это залогировать и понять что произошло.

Comment: @ffk А что делать, если, скажем, у нас 15 уровней вложения вызовов методов, и возникла ошибка? Как предполагается отслеживать, из-за чего возникла ошибка где-то «снизу»? Мы можем отследить аргументы ф-ии, но не кем она была вызвана, может сам вызов был ошибочным (если это шаблон). Код, конечно, очень засоряется, но зато каскад исключений сводит мою отладку к одной-нескольким минутам. А в моем проекте крайне сложно отслеживать проблемы, т.к. это распределенная агентная сеть.

Comment: Сложно сказать, не знаю вашу архитектуру, возможно она не очень удачна. Какие могут быть решения: 1) Любая современная IDE может останавливать программу в момент бросания исключения, даже может останавливать по конкретному типу. Т.е. вы можете в дебагере повторить сценарий приводящий к исключению и иследовать стек. 2) В момент бросания исключения можно попытаться сохранить стек внутри исключения. Под windows ключевое слово `dbghelp.lib` под linux не знаю, надо искать.

Comment: 3) Самому сэмулировать stakc trace. Т.е. в начеле каждой (или ключевой) функции вставить макрос STACK_TRACE, который будет запоминать текущее имя файла, функцию и номер строки, а в момент броса исключения получить доступ до сохраненного стека и сохранить его в исключение. Можно бросание исключение завенуть в макрос и все будет прозрачнее для программиста. P.S. макрос и весь механизм надо писать самому или поискать что-нибудь готовое